# Why did Dumbledore put so many obstacles to protect The Philosopher's stone when it’s pretty much pointless?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, philosophers-stone

This has always struck me as odd, in Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone,  Harry, Ron, and Hemione get past 7 obstacles in order to stop Quirrell. Although, even if Harry and his pals don’t show up, Quirrell still wouldn’t have gotten the stone. Why? It’s because of the enchantments Dumbledore himself put. Quirrell would never have gotten the stone because his intentions weren’t honorable. That renders the others kind of pointless. When I say “kind of pointless” I mean **they do not need to be there**, Dumbledore could have set the mirror in Quirrell's office and he still wouldn’t have gotten the stone. So why all these death traps Dumbledore? Besides, If Dumbledore really wanted the students to keep out, he should have made it harder to get to then just:[image]

Even Umbridge is able to seal her office from the likes of *Alohomora*, **but this is guarding the Philosopher's stone we’re talking about**! Plus, on Christmas, Harry finds The Mirror of Erised and looks into it. In case you need a refresher, Hagrid took the stone from the vault in July and it is now December so why is it taking so long to put the stone, in the mirror, in the chamber? Uh, so why is the mirror up in the school when it should be down in the chamber? Why are there so many obstacles when they’re pointless?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did Dumbledore make it less difficult to get to the Sorcerer's Stone?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/122400/31394)

Comment: Yes it does, thankyou!

Comment: My headcanon guess is that it was a trap. The stone was threatened before, and Dumbledore suspects one of his teachers. So he involves all the teachers in setting traps for the stone - at least, that's what he tells them. The only actual protection is the mirror, which he believes is unbreakable. By having all the other teachers work on it he is tempting them to stick their necks out and get caught.

Comment: So it was just a trap?

Comment: No, it is a either just giant plot hole, or Dumbledore wants to risk Harry's life, maybe even wants him to be killed.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That question seems to be asking the opposite?

Comment: @Alex I wouldn't have closehammered it if the OP hadn't said "yes it does" in response to "does this answer your question?"